# Sending Mail with PlayFramework

Tags: java, email, playframework, jakarta-mail, playframework-2.5

### application.conf

```
play.mailer {
host=smtp.gmail.com
port=25
ssl=true
tls=false
user="wahid.****.com"
password="A******f"
debug=false
mock=false
}
```

### build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0"
```

### My Controller

```
public class MySampleMail {

@Inject MailerClient mailerClient;

public void sendEmail() {
    String cid = "1234";
    Email email = new Email()
            .setSubject("Simple email")
            .setFrom("wahid.************.com")
            .addTo("w***********.com")
            .setBodyText("A text message");
    mailerClient.send(email);
}
}
```

But This send(email) is giving   Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]]

Comment: What Play version do you use ?

Comment: I m using Playframework 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;
public class Main 
private static String USER_NAME = "+++++++++++++++";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
private static String PASSWORD = "++++++++++"; // GMail password
private static String RECIPIENT = "++++++++++++++";

public static void mainMethod() {
    String from = USER_NAME;
    String pass = PASSWORD;
    String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
    String subject = "Java send mail example";
    String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

    sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
}

private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch (AddressException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Working fine but I need for Playframework 2.5 mailclient.

Comment: The SMTP port in this example - 587 - is different to the port in your code - 25.  Try correcting that.